# Can I create a for loop with two variables and still have time complexity of O(n)?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Say I have a for loop as:

```
for(int i=0,j=i+1;i<n-1,j<n;j++)
{
    //some code
    if(condition)
    {
        i++;
        j=i;
    }    
}
```

What will be the time complexity and why?

Edited:

```
void printAllAPTriplets(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)  
    { 

        // Search other two elements of  
        // AP with arr[i] as middle. 
        for (int j = i - 1, k = i + 1; j >= 0 && k < n;)  
        { 

            // if a triplet is found 
            if (arr[j] + arr[k] == 2 * arr[i])  
            { 
                cout << arr[j] << " " << arr[i] 
                     << " " << arr[k] << endl; 

                // Since elements are distinct, 
                // arr[k] and arr[j] cannot form 
                // any more triplets with arr[i] 
                k++; 
                j--; 
            } 

            // If middle element is more move to  
            // higher side, else move lower side. 
            else if (arr[j] + arr[k] < 2 * arr[i])  
                k++;          
            else
                j--;          
        } 
    } 
}
```

What would be the time complexity of this particular function and why?? @walnut @DeducibleSteak @Acorn .This is the code for "Printing all triplets in sorted array that form AP"

Comment: Stil the same complexity since if you would have let say n to be N than if you would have 2*N than its still linearly increasing complexity so the amount of work is done is became 2 times more, thus the complexity is O(n).

Comment: What is `condition` supposed to be? If it can depend on `i` and `j` and/or modify `i` and `j`, then this could have any complexity.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what your loop does? For example, the "i<n-1" condition is just ignored - the result of the comma operator is the value of the right-most comma separated expression. Also, you will not just magically get O(n) from O(n^2) by formatting your for loops a bit differently. You will get it by doing n times less work.

Answer (score 1):

O(n^2) is when you iterate through all the possible values of one variable each time you iterate through the second one. As such:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++{
//Do some action
}
}
```

In your example, even though you're using two vars, but it's still a O(n).
Assuming that increasing `i` by one takes one second, then assigning the new `i` to `j` takes one second too, then the complexity is `O(2n)`. Since constant numbers are insignificant when speaking about complexities, then the complexity of your code is still `O(n)`

Comment: The condition could be e.g. `j==n-1`, then the loop will run `Theta(n^2)` times.

Comment: I agree with you. I think the question in the title is different than the actual one. In the title the question was: "Could there be a for loop with 2 variables and complexity of O(n)?" .. And I think I answered that. But then the question became: "what is the complexity of this particular code?", to which the answer is: "it depends on your if condition"

Answer (score 0):

The loop you have written does not make sense, because you are using the comma operator and discarding one of the conditions, so it is equivalent to `j < n`.

Even if the condition gets triggered many times (but a constant number w.r.t. `n`, i.e. not becoming larger as `n` grows), then you can easily show you will do `<= k*n` iterations, which means O(n) iterations.

If that is not true, but the condition is at least side-effect free, then you can only bound it by O(n^2), e.g. as @walnut suggests with `j == n - 1` (like in a triangle matrix).

If you allow for side-effects in the condition (e.g. `j = 0`, with an equals sign), then it can be an infinite loop, so there is no possible bound.

Comment: i have used this loop in few questions and it actually gives me the right output for whatever input i give. It does make sense!! I just wasn't sure about the time complexity.

Comment: The condition could be `j==n-1`, then the loop will run `Theta(n^2)` times.

Comment: @walnut If `condition` triggers a number of times that may be as large as `n`, indeed. It could also be an infinite loop if the condition is not side-effect free, so... ;P I will edit to make it more precise.

Comment: @Acorn Yes, the question isn't really clear. That's why I asked OP as well (but no response so far...).

Comment: @mrkc25 Then it will be `Theta(n^2)` which implies `O(n^2)` and implies *not* `O(n)`. Please edit your question to clarify it. At least mention whether you  want `condition` to allow `i` and `j` to be modified and whether you want to know whether there *exists any `condition`* so that it is `O(n)` (see your title) or whether you are asking that it is `O(n)` for *all* possible `condition`. (seemingly what your question body asks).